# Session not maintained between mysite.com and www.example.com

Tags: php, session-variables

I am using a session to maintain some variables between different pages on my site. While it works fine when I move from www.example.com/a to www.example.com/b, the session variables are lost if I move from example.com/a to www.example.com/b

Any idea how I can make sure the session is maintained irrespective of www or no www?

The website appends a www as it navigates to different pages but the pages are accessible without that as well. So if someone is manually typing in an address and omit that part, and then navigate to page b (by clicking on a link or submitting a form), the session variables are lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reasonable way to do it is by redirecting `example.com` to `www.example.com`; by that you make sure that all your visitors are in `www.example.com`, and crawlers won't index two pages with the same content.

You do that by sending a `301: Moved Permanently` to users accessing `example.com` (assuming you use apache, you have to add this to your `.htaccess`):

```
Redirect 301 http://example.com/ http://www.example.com/
```

<s>Second version:</s>

```
Redirect 301 http://example.com/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1
```

Sorry, this one is right:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Taken from here http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php

Comment: +1 - this is the cleaner way to do it, assuming www.mysite.com is the same site logically as mysite.com

Comment: Thanks. I'll go with this. Just one question - If I pass a parameter with a URL (that does not have a www), will the redirect pass the parameter to the www URL automatically?

Comment: don't know for sure, but the second version should.

Answer (score 2):

you need to make sure the cookie is being set to .example.com not www.example.com using `session_set_cookie_params`, specifically parameter 3 - the domain in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

Comment: Setting the domain to ".example.com" would make more sense if he wants the session values to be available under both domains.

Answer (score 0):

The session ID is stored in a cookie. Cookies don't transfer over from subdomain to subdomain (e.g. www.somesite.com to somesite.com). You can change the cookie params with [session_set_cookie_params()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) or in [php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)