# Session is not passing throughout the links

Tags: php, url, session, ssl

I have been having this problem and could not find the proper answer to it.
I am building my website in php and i am using sessions for users to be able to make the pages function accordingly.
However session is not passing to the links if it is not in the same typical sequence. I am using ssl on in every page so it is coming as https wherever you go
and my problem as follows:
Link: https//webmasteroutlet.com and user signs in and as long as the URL stays as  without WWW at the beginning the user seems logged in. The moment it goes with www it does not recognize or pass the session and user looks not logged in
same thing happens when user is in the URl with WWW and then it turns to the one with no WWW in it.
Please help me how can i fix this.
Thank You

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cookies And Subdomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723788/cookies-and-subdomain)

Answer (score 0):

Session IDs are stored in cookies.  For the purpose of cookies, mysite.com and www.mysite.com are two different websites.  This is very close to the following question:

[Session not maintained between mysite.com and www.example.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975076/session-not-maintained-between-mysite-com-and-www-mysite-com)

Comment: Thanks Nick i already read those answers before i posted but i am adding https if it is not, so i am using some other lines of code to add https and i do not know how to do the both that is why

Comment: this is what i have currently 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
i dont know about htaccess files at all and i need https on all the time along with www i could not find anybody doing that.

Comment: When setting the cookie, you can put a .mysite.com and it should work with and without www.  
Also, you can try:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
Found that at: http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/redirect-domain-www-subdomain.shtml

Comment: I am using sessions only. can is there a way i can set session for .mysite.com? Otherwise i will try the htaccess code. Thank you

Comment: When you set the cookie, set it for .mysite.com http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php